# Python Class Inheritance: Calling a function of a derivative class

Tags: python, class

The `my_car.drive_car()` method is meant to update `ElectricCar`'s member variable `condition` to `"like new"` but still calls `drive_car` from the `Car` super class.

```
    my_car = ElectricCar("Flux capacitor", "DeLorean", "silver", 88)

    print my_car.condition #Prints "New"
    my_car.drive_car()
    print my_car.condition #Prints "Used"; is supposed to print "Like New"
```

Am I missing something?  Is there a more elegant way to override superclass functions?

`class ElectricCar` inherits from the super `class Car`

```
    class Car(object):
            condition = "new"

            def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
                    self.model, self.color, self.mpg = model, color, mpg

            def drive_car(self):
                    self.condition = "used"

    class ElectricCar(Car):
            def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
                    self.battery_type = battery_type
                    super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)

            def drive_car(self):
                    self.condition = "like new"
```

Comment: it works for me. prints: new, like new

Comment: @pylover He wasn't asking if it works, though.

Comment: @pylover It's supposed to print "like new" I'll update my post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question being asked. Are you complaining that `self.condition` is being set incorrectly? Like pylover I can't reproduce that. Are you asking for something different, like changing `display_car` in some way? You don't seem to have tried that.

Comment: @pylover @Blckknght My mistake. When `drive_car` is called on an `ElectricCar` object, the `condition` should be updated to "like new" However, my code still calls `drive_car` from the super `class Car` I'm not sure why.

Comment: I recommend you to delete all codes you have, and copy+paste the codes  from this post and try again. may be you are sleepy or something else

Answer (score 0):

You're defining condition as a class variable instead of an instance variable. Do this:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model, self.color, self.mpg = model, color, mpg
        self.condition = "new"

    def drive_car(self):
        self.condition = "used"

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, battery_type, model, color, mpg):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, color, mpg)
        self.battery_type = battery_type

    def drive_car(self):
        self.condition = "like new"
```